# Images loop and videos loop don't line up correctly

Tags: php, css, image, loops, video

[image: The videos don't line up with the images]

I have td container where I use php to loop through a set of videos and a set of images. Each image and video are in a div with the same class, but for some reason the videos end up higher than the images. Any idea what causes this?

two PHP loops that output an html div for each image/video:

```
<td colspan="5" style="max-width: 1000px; overflow-x: auto;">
<?php
$fk = $db_table_row["images_fk"];
$image_row = find_images_by_id($fk);//get images from an sql table
for ($i = 1; $i < count($image_row)+1; $i++) {
    if($image_row[$i] != null){
        echo "<div id='media_wrap'><img src='{$image_row[$i]}' height='200'/>&nbsp</div>";
    }
}

$fk = $db_table_row["videos_fk"];
$video_row = find_videos_by_id($fk);//get videos from an sql table
for ($i = 1; $i < count($video_row)+1; $i++) {
    if($video_row[$i] != null){
        echo "<div id='media_wrap'><video width=\"270\" height=\"200\" controls><source src=\"{$video_row[$i]}\"></video>&nbsp</div>";

    }
}
?>
</td>
```

The wrap div css:

```
 #media_wrap{display: inline; white-space: nowrap; max-height: 200px;}
```

If I make 2 video or 2 image loops they line up perfectly. If I put the videos loop before the image loop then the images end up higher.

They are all set to 200 height, and are in the same id="media_wrap" div, so they should behave the same right?

**EDIT:**
it was caused by having bootstrap in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I could take it out, but I might really need it for dropdown menus later :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix :)

You're setting max-height on the parent `#media_wrap`, when it needs to be applied to the children. You should define it in either `#media_wrap img, #media_wrap video` or `#media_wrap *` instead. Then you just need to float the two divs next to each other :) Note that neither `display: inline` or `white-space: nowrap` are necessary.

Also note that you're also defining two divs with the same ID, which is very bad practice. Instead, I recommend giving both of your divs a class of `media_wrap` instead of using it as an ID.

Finally, note that for questions pertaining to CSS, it helps to include a copy of the actual HTML output, rather than the code used to execute the output :)

I've created a fiddle with both images and videos forcibly scaled down in height, displayed next to each other. I also replaced your IDs with classes of the same name, and added a slight offset. The fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t80t44vc/3/).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Based on your new comments, images, and code, I've got a slightly better idea of what you're trying to achieve. As such, I've slightly modified the code.

Note that you can't have two divs displayed next to each other in combination with a horizontal scrollbar. As such, I've combined both the images and video into one div.

Also, now `white-space: nowrap` **is** required ;)

New code: https://jsfiddle.net/85kd0wma/

Now images and videos have a fixed height, and will display next to each other with a horizontal scrollbar. Hopefully this is what you're after :)

Comment: Thanks, that part worked, but it also created another problem. If I have a container like this: https://jsfiddle.net/t80t44vc/5/ where I want it to create a scroll bar left-right if there are too many images/videos, it looks like the overflow-x is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've updated my answer to address your new problem :)

Comment: So I did the exact same thing and they were not lined up again. Then I kinda dismentled everything and found out that this line: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> in the header causes it. I kinda need bootstrap for other things, so maybe ther's a way to override whatever it does to the images?

Comment: You can certainly override Bootstrap. What part of Bootstrap's CSS is causing the problem? If you're still using a class of `.container`, note that it is a pre-defined name for a Bootstrap class. You can try renaming your classes (though that may mess up some display reliant on Bootstrap), adding more specificity to the selectors in your CSS, or adding `!important` to your values, (such as `white-space: nowrap !important`) -- Doing any of those should fix a clash with Bootstrap :)

Comment: I have no clue which part of bootstrap is it :( Just tried to add !important to everything in media_wrap and a few other things but it did nothing. Maybe I can only include bootstrap in the nav bar with a separate css file without it for the rest of the page?

Comment: Bootstrap shouldn't be breaking it, and it wouldn't be possible to include it for only half of a page. Try either a) using Developer Tools to turn off every single selector affecting `.container` or `.media_wrap`  until it gets back to a working state, or b) add parts of your site onto my example fiddle, until it breaks. That way you can isolate **exactly** which single selector is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So on jsfiddle it worked with the bootstrap link, but when i copied the exact same code to my project it didn't work. I made sure i'm testing a 100% independent file that I can copy 100% in jsfiddle. even tried to put it in some of my other projects to make sure it's not being affected by anything that's no in jsfiddle.

In the end I just forced it to work with top: 0;

```
<?php $left = 0; ?>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: <?php echo $left; $left+=205; ?>px;" src='http://placehold.it/200x200' height='200'/>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: <?php echo $left; $left+=205; ?>px;" src='http://placehold.it/200x200' height='200'/>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: <?php echo $left; $left+=205; ?>px;" src='http://placehold.it/200x200' height='200'/>
        <video width='270' height='200' style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: <?php echo $left; $left+=275; ?>px;" controls><source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'></video>
        <video width='270' height='200' style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: <?php echo $left; $left+=275; ?>px;" controls><source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'></video>
        <video width='270' height='200' style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: <?php echo $left; $left+=275; ?>px;" controls><source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'></video>
```

thanks for the help Obsidian Age :D